# Fragment addToBackStack() and popBackStackImmediate() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I am currently building an application for Android (14 <= SDK <= 21) by using one `ActionBarActivity` and more `Fragments`, such as `ListFragment` and `MapFragment`, which are swapped within a single `FrameLayout` view.

The ActionBarActivity automatically replace/commit fragment A. Then, when the user tap a button, the hosting Activity replace/commit a new different fragment B. My goal is to let the user go back on fragment A as soon as she presses the back button.

Some code now.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements StopFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    StopItemFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);
        ...
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame) == null) {
            StopItemFragment list = StopItemFragment.newInstance(null); //A - extends ListFragment
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, list)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        }
        ...

        @Override
        public void onFragmentInteraction(String id) {
        selectItem(Integer.parseInt(id));
        }


       private void selectItem(int position) {
       StopFragment fragment = StopFragment.newInstance(null, null); //B - extends Fragment
       ...
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

       ...
       }
}
```

**Problem**

Even if `addToBackStack()` is called, when I am on fragment B, I am not able to go back to fragment A. MainActivity is directly closed.
Yet I tried to manage the back stack by myself with no luck. I can see that the fragment is on the stack but if I call `popBackStackImmediate()`, fragment A is popped out and the fragment transaction is not performed. (first back press nothing happen, second activity closed)

I attach also the FragmentManager logcat:
http://pastebin.com/hFLHprL8

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For those, who are still looking for solution.

In the main `Activity` class (which is hosting the fragments)just override `onBackPressed()`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

There is no `onBackPressed()` method in fragment, and this method is just for the `activity`. So,when we press the back key, the default behaviour of `activity` is shown, which is

> you will either go to previous activity(if there is any) or the app
>   will exit.

Now we need to override this method to tell the `activity` that when we press the back key, if there are any fragments in back stack, pop them out (and this is when the `addToBackStack()` comes into picture). Otherwise follow the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why android documentation didn't mention this important thing?, or I just miss it...

Answer (score 6):

Try this (Note **add** not **replace** for fragmentA, and **addToBackStack()** for fragmentB)

```
StopItemFragment list = StopItemFragment.newInstance(null); //A - extends ListFragment
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_frame, list)
            .commit();
```

and

```
StopFragment fragment = StopFragment.newInstance(null, null); //B - extends Fragment
   ...
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
        .addToBackStack("FragmentB")
        .commit();
```

Comment: In that way I add on the stack fragment B but not A.

From `FragmentTransaction` documentation:
     `addToBackStack(): Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.`

Answer (score 5):

I had to call `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` of `FragmentManager` manually.
Solved by overriding `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ...
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1){
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().commit();
    } else {
        //handle finish
        finish(); // Closes app
    }
}
```

Comment: `popBackStackImmediate` is slower than `popBackStack` in order to avoid performance issues use `popBackStack` where ever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Struggling with addToBackStack() & popBackStack() then simply use

```
FragmentTransaction ft =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment(), "Home");
ft.commit();`
```

In your Activity In OnBackPressed() find out fargment by tag and then do your stuff

```
Fragment home = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Home");

if (home instanceof HomeFragment && home.isVisible()) {
    // do you stuff
}
```

For more Information https://github.com/DattaHujare/NavigationDrawer 
 I never use addToBackStack() for handling fragment.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the `popBackStack()` and `popBackStackImmediatly()` is due to the fact that you didnt add that fragment (that you want to pop) to the backStack. In order to do this you have to make a call to addToBackStack() at the moment of making the transaction to add/replace your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wanted to say a big thank you to the highlighted [Nick]'s answer (Low reputation can't comment underneath), for helping me know there WAS actually something that didn't get mentioned in the Android Documentations.

Second, it's 2019 now, and after stumbling for a similar way in Androidx's Preferences, I couldn't find anything for a long time, until I was both checking this question and an [official sample code in Kotlin](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-preferences/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidx/preference/sample/MainActivity.kt), which this question led to a clue and the sample code's way actually was the solution in my case, works like a charm with a very tiny piece of overwriting, hope it helps as well for those who are looking for an official solution

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

[Aforementioned code in Java (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiU6r.png)

P.S. My first answer EVER on stacksoverflow, after more than of at least 5 years of using it ^^