# Fragments, How to maintain BackStack using Fragments , if Layout is created Runtime?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating Layout Runtime, I am unable to get the previous UI-state with data, when i using getFragmentManager().popBackStack(), instead it pops the default UI-state and omits UI-state changed at Runtime.

I have One Activity, in which onMenuItemSelected() i used switch to get the corresponding click events. I have own logic in each case, using methods. So i have created custom Fragment class to inflate Layout, using Interface, i handled the layout events again in the Activity class.

If custom Fragment class inflates a Layout which has some default UI, as well as Runtime UI-elements can be add/remove. At this point, I have add/remove UI-elements in custom Fragment class itself, and not using Fragment Interface(means my Activity class don't know if UI-element is added).

I want to store UI-state with data. How to do ?

Comment: what you try for opening fragment ..?

Comment: try it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693754/fragment-addtobackstack-and-popbackstackimmediate-not-working

Comment: @pkBhati above link is not my solution, i tried already what is given